# AMcharts 4 - valueAxis.positionToValue() does not exist

Tags: amcharts4

In the [docs for Amcharts 4](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/tracking-cursors-position-via-api/) there is this example for tracking the cursor position:

```
chart.cursor.events.on("cursorpositionchanged", function(ev) {
 let xAxis = ev.target.chart.xAxes.getIndex(0);
 let yAxis = ev.target.chart.yAxes.getIndex(0);
 console.log("x: ", xAxis.positionToDate(xAxis.toAxisPosition(ev.target.xPosition)));
 console.log("y: ", yAxis.positionToValue(yAxis.toAxisPosition(ev.target.yPosition)));
});
```

but I am getting the error

> Property 'positionToValue' does not exist on type 'Axis'

and the same for `positionToDate`. There is a method `positionToCoordinate` but that does not provide what I need (i.e. conversion back to the actual units driving the chart). I only need `positionToValue`, I am not using dates.

Comment: No answers here after a week. I tried moving to AmCharts 5 - this allowed `positionToValue` but then  didn't appear to show a chart at all! So I have given up with AMCharts and am  using chart.js instead.